# SQL rowversion support by entity framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, rowversion

My project uses EF (tested with version 4 using self-tracking template and with version 5 using default templates, all database-first) against SQL Server 2012. The database tables have each a `rowversion` (`timestamp`) column defined.

Using EF in it core, meaning my code on database updates looking so:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
  //db.Entry(myInstance).State = EntityState.Modified;
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

does not trigger any `rowversion` alerts. I run parallel clients, each reads the same record, makes a change to it and then each writes it to the database. All updates are accepted, no concurrency is applied.

Do I have to work with stored procedures for my update commands (with a where clause that states my `rowversion` value) to have EF acknowledge the "built-in" concurrency or is there another way (configuration, specific method calls) to make my code work?

Answer (score 9):

### Here's the answer (I've given it a couple of weeks to POC):

1. `RowVersion` (or the `TimeStamp` field type) in `SQL` is a field as any other (except for being mandatory and self incrementing). There is a specific database handling of its value on updates (i.e. incrementing it), but there is no specific database handling comparing its value before update.
2. `EF` on the other side allows you to define `ConcurrencyMode` for each field (`edmx`). You might, if you want, mark all your fields with `ConcurrencyMode=Fix` (instead of the default `None`), and thus include all of them within the update's where-clause (comparing the entity's original values with the record's current values in the database). But it's easier to set one field per entity, i.e. the `RowVersion` field, with that mode. Especially since the only party maintaining it for you is the database.
3. Once you've done that, you're sure to get the `System.Data.OptimisticConcurrencyException` isolation error. You still have to keep away from `EF` workflows which manipulate your object sets, such as the use of `myObjectSet.Attach(myEntity)`, which makes a trip to the database to fetch the current data and merges your changes into it. Since the `RowVersion` field is normally unchanged, the update will trigger with the current value from the database, and will not result in the concurrency exception.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to handle concurrency if so take a look at this link:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application