Update() method is working but Create() is not in C# API
My code is an API that updates and creates various tables in the database. For every other class it is working except this class: Operacao. The method Update() works fine, but Create() doesn't work.
This is the class:
public class Operacao
{
    public virtual short OperacaoID { get; set; }
    public virtual short? Codigo { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual string? Descricao { get; set; }
    public virtual bool FlagAtivo { get; set; }
    public virtual bool FlagPadrao { get; set; }
    public virtual int DtUpdate { get; set; }
}

This is the input data from the user:
public class OperacaoDados
{
    [Key]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public short OperacaoID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual string? Descricao { get; set; }
}

And this is the controller:
 [HttpPost]
 [Authorize]
 public async Task<ActionResult> PostOperacao(OperacaoDados operacaoDados)
 {
     var operacaoExistente = await _context.Operacao
                                           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Nome == operacaoDados.Nome);

     DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
     long ticks = dateTime.Ticks;
     int dataInteiro = (int)(ticks & 0xFFFFFFFF);

     if (operacaoExistente != null)
     {
         operacaoExistente.Descricao = operacaoDados.Descricao;
         operacaoExistente.FlagAtivo = true;

         try
         {
             await _operacaoRepository.Update(operacaoExistente);
             return Ok("Operação atualizada com sucesso");
         }
         catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
         {
             // Handle the concurrency exception here
             return Conflict("A operação que você está tentando atualizar foi modificada por outro usuário.");
         }
     }
     else
     {
         Operacao novoOperacao = new Operacao
                  {
                      Codigo = short.Parse(operacaoDados.Nome),
                      DtUpdate = dataInteiro,
                      Nome = operacaoDados.Nome,
                      Descricao = operacaoDados.Descricao,
                      FlagAtivo = true,
                      FlagPadrao = false
                  };

         var result = await _operacaoRepository.Create(novoOperacao);

         if (result != null)
         {
             return Ok("Operação cadastrada com sucesso");
         }

         return BadRequest("Erro ao salvar Operação");
    }
}

And this is the repository:
  public async Task<Operacao> Create(Operacao operacao)
  {
      _context.Operacao.Add(operacao);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

      return operacao;
  }

  public async Task Update(Operacao operacao)
  {
      _context.Entry(operacao).State = EntityState.Modified;
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  }

The error happens when it saves in this method: await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); in the Create() method.
This is the error:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information:
Executed DbCommand (12ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Int16), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (DbType = Int32), @p3='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p4='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p5='?' (Size = 4000)],
CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Operacao] ([Codigo], [Descricao], [DtUpdate], [FlagAtivo], [FlagPadrao], [Nome])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5);
SELECT [OperacaoID]
FROM [Operacao]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [OperacaoID] = scope_identity();
Exceção gerada:
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
Exceção gerada:
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' em System.Private.CoreLib.dll


You get a DbUpdateConcurrencyException error when the records you expected to update are not found. Its odd that you get an update error for an insert command.  Maybe a trigger is updating another table.

Similar error here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329094/dbupdateconcurrencyexception-on-add

Please share the table design of Operacao. The data type for DtUpdate might not be compatible with int.

This is my table design in SQL:
[dbo].[Operacao](
[OperacaoID] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Codigo] [smallint] NULL,
[Nome] varchar NOT NULL,
[Descricao] varchar NULL,
[FlagAtivo] [bit] NOT NULL,
[FlagPadrao] [bit] NOT NULL,
[DtUpdate] [int] NOT NULL,
[dbo].[Operacao] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DFC_DTU_Operacao]  DEFAULT ((-1893456000)) FOR [DtUpdate]

What happens when you try to enter the same record by hand via your database tool (SSMS)?

I don't see [RowVersion] in your table. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193961/sql-rowversion-support-by-entity-framework

When I enter the records via SSMS it works out. But I noticed sometimes the id seems random. Here are the registers I made and the id it returned:
"OperacaoID Codigo Nome Descricao FlagAtivo FlagPadrao DtUpdate"
"300 999 999 teste4 1 0 -1443190411"
"333 666 666 teste 1 0 -1443169846"
"337 667 667 teste 1 0 -1443169799"
"338 668 668 teste 1 0 -1443169780"

Did you also run this part of your query?  SELECT [OperacaoID], [RowVersion]
FROM [Operacao]

My bad, the RowVersion field was removed. Now I changed the question and edited the code to reflect this.

The 'SELECT [OperacaoID] FROM [Operacao] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [OperacaoID] = scope_identity();' is not returning any value. I think the error is in my database then. What do you think?

Thank you Bart. It was an error in my SQL. The problem was resolved by removing the triggers in my table Operacao. Thank you very much for your help!

You get a DbUpdateConcurrencyException error when the records you expected to update are not found. It is odd that you get an update error for an insert command. In my experience this can happen when a trigger deletes the row you just inserted.

I figured it out. It was an error in my SQL. The problem was resolved by removing the triggers in my table Operacao.

Great! I got it on my first guess. :)
